# Convergence of the RLS Algorithm for a Forgetting Factor $ \lambda < 1 $

Tags: python, adaptive-filters, stability, adaptive-algorithms, numerical-algorithms

I have a question regarding **Recursive Least Squares** (RLS) adaptive filter.

According to Wikipedia ([Recursive Least Squares in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_least_squares_filter)), to prevent infinite memory one introduces a forgetting factor $0 < \lambda \le 1$. Then the RLS recursive update equations are:
[image]

The relevant update is:

$$
\mathbf{P}(n) = \lambda^{-1} \cdot \left( \mathbf{P}(n-1) -\mathbf{g}(n)\mathbf{x}^T(n) \mathbf{P}(n-1) \right).
$$

Unless there is some "magical cancellation" then $\mathbf{P}(n) \propto \lambda^{-n}$ which tends to infinity as $n$ grows (since $\lambda^{-1} > 1$). Which means that after long time the filter will "explode" and cause overflow which will ruin the output signal.

I tested the RLS in a Python code, and found that as $\lambda$ decreases, the time-point in which the matrix $\mathbf{P}(n)$ diverges (practically, when I encounter an *overflow* in $\mathbf{P}(n)$) comes sooner.

Since all papers and Wikipedia define $\lambda < 1$ and the formula for $\mathbf{P}$ goes with $\lambda^{-1}$, I assume this well-tested algorithm somehow addresses the issue of divergence.
Why the algorithm does not diverge in theory and practice and what should I do to prevent it diverge when processing very long streams of data?

Side note: I am actually using the RLS for complex signals, therefore transpose ($A^T$) should be replaced with hermitian conjugate ($A^H = \bar{H}^T$) and one needs to pay attention for complex conjugates.

Comment: Well, having $\lambda < 1$ alone does not guarantee divergence, does it? Divergence depends on the term in parenthesis as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The convergence itself depends on the eigen values of the empirical correlation matrix (See remark below).

By setting $ \lambda \leq 1 $ we allow the filter to adapt in the non stationary cases.

We can think that also the factor basically damps the eigen values of the matrix if $ \lambda > 1 $.
In the case $ \lambda < 1 $ you may thing that you increase the eigen values, yet not necessarily above the critical value for convergence.

Specifically, for you equation of interest:

$$ P = {\lambda}^{-1} \left( P  - \boldsymbol{x} \boldsymbol{g}^{T} P \right) = {\lambda}^{-1} \left( I - \boldsymbol{x} \boldsymbol{g}^{T} \right) P $$

Now, in order to have convergence for the equation above what's needed is that $ {\lambda}^{-1} \left( I - \boldsymbol{x} \boldsymbol{g}^{T} \right) $ will have all eigen values within the unit circle. It can happen for $ \lambda < 1 $ as it depends not only on it.

**Remark**: Actually for $ \lambda \in \left( 0, 1 \right] $ it can be shown that for any bounded input the algorithm will converge regardless of the eigen values.

**Remark**: If you want to read more about the specific case, you may look for the term *convergence of fixed point iterations*. For instance [Marta Čertíková - FPI for Linear Systems - Fixed Point Iterations](https://marta.certik.cz/NM/Afix.pdf) (On [Web Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20230214080613/https://marta.certik.cz/NM/Afix.pdf)). She has a great course [NUMERICAL MATHEMATICS](https://marta.certik.cz/ANM.html).

Comment: Actually, I asked how RLS converges if $\mathbf{P}(n) \propto \lambda^{-n}$ when $\lambda < 1$. When I implemented it with $\lambda = 0.95$ it diverges after about 1000 iterations and when I decreased it to $\lambda = 0.5$ it diverged much faster (after less than 300 iterations).

Comment: The reasoning is the same, It depends on the eigen values of the multiplication and not only on $\lambda$. I will update accordingly.

Comment: Thank you. If I understand correctly the term $I - \mathbf{g}\mathbf{x}^T$ is the term that ensures convergence, provided that its largest eigenvalue is smaller than $\lambda$. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, they are both must be a contraction operator. Your intuition is correct, just that $ \lambda $ is not the only term in play.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem as you, when I use the step like follows
[image]

The matrix $P(n)$ diverges, which using $z^H(n)$ instead of $x^{T}(n)P(n-1)$.

Then I using the fomular
$$P(n) = \lambda^{-1} \cdot (P(n-1) - g(n)x^{T}(n)P(n-1))$$

$P(N)$ become convergence，only by change the calculation order.

**The algorithm is sensitivity to roundoff noise that accumulates due to the recursive computations, which may cause instabilities in the algorithm.**

hope this helps.